# Reset package options

Tags: errors, packages, glossaries

\LaTeX seems to remember earlier stated options. How can I reset this?

```
    ! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package glossaries.
    See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
    Type H <return> for immediate help.
    ...
    l.14
    The package glossaries has already been loaded with options        
    [nonumberlist,toc,acronym,xindy]
    There has now been an attempt to load it with options
    [ nonumberlist, acronym, toc, section]
    Adding the global options:
    nonumberlist,toc,acronym,xindy, nonumberlist, acronym, toc, section
    to your \documentclass declaration may fix this.
    Try typing <return> to proceed.
```

Comment: You can not reset it, the package is not reloaded a second time, you just need to load the package earlier with the combined option list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As David mentioned in his comment, you can't reload a package (`\usepackage` will skip any packages that have already been loaded), but with `glossaries` it's possible to change *some* of the options after the package has been loaded using `\setupglossaries` (described in the [Setting Options After the Package is Loaded](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#sec%3asetupglossaries) section of the user manual). So you can, for example, do:

```
\setupglossaries{nonumberlist,toc,section}
```

But the `acronym` and `xindy`/`makeindex` options (along with some others) can't be changed after the package has been loaded.

Comment: Old question and no longer relevant for me, but thx for answering. The problem was caused by an included config file I overlooked. That file had already included those packages.

Answer (score 1):

With the command `\PassOptionsToPackage`, you can choose options *before* loading the package for the first time: if necessary even before your `\documentclass` preamble, in case that is where the package is loaded.

Example:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage[nonumberlist, acronym, toc, section]{glossaries}
\documentclass{article}
```

To my understanding, it adds to the option list, it does not override further options.

More info [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-optionclash.html)